# How to run metro server with environment variables for detox mocking

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm trying to get advanced mocking to work with detox. Following this [guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md). I'm having trouble starting the metro server with environment variables. I'm using react-native 0.62.2

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In Windows you get set environment variables like:

```
set "RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js" && react-native start
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/